# AJAX multiple inputs not passing or sending data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been battling with this AJAX to pass data to PHP for SQL Insertion, it seems the data does not get passed to the PHP. I have three HTML input types, text, radio button and select. The radio is used for `gender`, select for the `country` of residence, and text for the country's `dialcode` concatenated with the user's `mobilenumber`. Javascript is used to automatically retrieve the `dialcode` once the user selects his/her `country` in the dropdown. These inputs are not being passed for SQL insertion.

I am still very much an amateur and a student. I included the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/406tb35r/1/

Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($){
     $(document).ready( function(){

        $('#country').change( function(e){
             //on change event 
            $('input[name="dialcode"]').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('co'));  
        });

    }); //make sure all html is loaded before running
 })(jQuery);  //assign jQuery to the $


function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

</script>
<form action="" method="post" class="start_form" id="userDetails">

        <fieldset>
          <legend><b>Are you a</b></legend>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="male">Male<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="female">Female<br>
      </fieldset> 
  <select id="country" name="country" class="country">
  <option data-co="" value="">Which country are from?</option>
  <option data-co="+27" value="ZA">South Africa</option>
  <option data-co="+376" value="AD">Andorra</option>
  <option data-co="+971" value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
  <option data-co="+93" value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  </select>
  <?php 
$countryArray = array(
  'AD'=>array('name'=>'ANDORRA','code'=>'376'),
  'AE'=>array('name'=>'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES','code'=>'971'),
  'AF'=>array('name'=>'AFGHANISTAN','code'=>'93'),
  'AG'=>array('name'=>'ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA','code'=>'1268'),
  );

function countrySelector($defaultCountry = "", $id = "", $name = "", $classes = ""){
    global $countryArray; 

    $output = "<select id='".$id."' name='".$name."' class='".$classes."'>";

  foreach($countryArray as $code => $country){
    $countryName = ucwords(strtolower($country["name"])); 
    $output .= "<option data-co='".$country["code"]."' value='".$code."' ".(($code==strtoupper($defaultCountry))?"selected":"").">".$code." - ".$countryName." (+".$country["code"].")</option>";
}

  $output .= "</select>";

  return $output;  
}
?>
<input align="center" type="text" name="dialcode" class="dialcode" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" mssg="" maxlength="6" readonly>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="mobile" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What is your Mobile Number?" mssg="" maxlength="12">

        <input style="width:100%;" type="submit" name="s_submit" value="Next" id="userSubmit"><br/>
        <a href="">Skip</a>
      </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('#userSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      var gender = $('.gender').val();
        var country = $('.country');
          var dialcode = $('.dialcode');
          var mobile = $('.mobile').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: DIR+'/insert.php',
      data: 
            gender: gender,
            country: country,
            dialcode: dialcode,
            mobile: mobile
      success:function(){
        $('.content').load(DIR+'/welcome.php');}
      }

    });

  });
});
</script>
```

This is the PHP for passing above data to SQL:

```
<?php
session_start();
//Connect to DB
  include_once 'connect.php';
   $session = $_SESSION['id'];
   $universal = new universal;
   $susername = $universal->GETsDetails($session, "username");

   if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

   $gender = preg_replace("#[<> ]#i", "", $_POST['gender']);
   $country = preg_replace("#[<> ]#i", "", $_POST['country']);
   $mobilenumber = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#i", "", $_POST['dialcode'] . $_POST['mobile']);

      if((!$username) == ""){
        return "Your details are not logged in or do not have an account with iamstein!";
      } else {
        $users = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET gender = :gender, country = :country, mobilenumber = :mobilenumber, WHERE id = :id");
        $users->execute(array(":gender" => $gender, ":country" => $country, "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber, ":id" => $session));

      }
 }?>
```

Comment: where's the wrapping curly braces for `data:` ?

Comment: Your data needs to be passed in with the right format.
(Out of Context) Hey Masood I'm a web developer from Emirates and would love to get in touch with you.

Comment: Hey, @Mohammed I'd be delighted. You can reach me at bawa.masood@gmail.com .

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly warp the data key

```
data: {
            gender: gender,
            country: country,
            dialcode: dialcode,
            mobile: mobile},
```

You weren't passing the right format for the data key.. Alternatively you can serialize the form, just to avoid this errors and mistakes.

```
data:$('#userDetails').serialize(),
```